# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (51,51) (100,)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to a assigment, but I get an error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (51,51) (100,)

```
def get_velocity(strength, xs, ys, X, Y,):

u = strength /(2*np.pi)*(X-xs)/((X-xs)**2 +(Y-ys)**2)
v = strength /(2*np.pi)*(Y-ys)/((X-xs)**2 +(Y-ys)**2)

return u, v
```

I want to use the function for some given points

```
x_naca0012 = np.loadtxt('NACA0012_x.txt')

y_naca0012 = np.loadtxt('NACA0012_y.txt')

strength_naca0012 = np.loadtxt('NACA0012_sigma.txt')
```

Using the function:

```
u_naca0012, v_naca0012 = get_velocity(strength_naca0012, x_naca0012, y_naca0012, X, Y)
```

Here it goes wrong, i search for the error and find something about not matching arrays, but I checked the lengths of each array and they match (100). What I noticed is that the 50th element of NACA0012_y is a positive value and the 51th element is a negative value. I think it messes up there.

Comment: There's an extra comma at the end of the definition of the `get_velocity`'s parameters; could that be a part of the issue?

Comment: If I run your function with three equally long 1D arrays, it works. Please look into more detail to the function arguments and try to reduce the problem, for instance to size 10, so you can post the actual input - if still relevant.

Comment: these are the files x_naca0012, y_naca0012 and strength_naca0012, respectievely.  [link](https://github.com/barbagroup/AeroPython/blob/master/lessons/resources/NACA0012_x.txt) [link] (https://github.com/barbagroup/AeroPython/blob/master/lessons/resources/NACA0012_y.txt) [link] (https://github.com/barbagroup/AeroPython/blob/master/lessons/resources/NACA0012_sigma.txt)

Comment: Sorry, if I download your files, the function still works for me. [tag:numpy] version 1.8.2, [tag:python] 2.7.6.

Comment: @Dr.V  :/ thank you for testing. When I try for a single number like x_naca0012 = -1 y_naca0012 = 0.5 and strength_naca0012 = 5, it works for me but as soon as i try x_naca0012 = numpy.array([-1,1]) y_naca0012= numpy.array([-0,25, 0.25]) and strength_naca0012 = numpy.array([5, 6]) i get the same error.

Comment: Now we get closer to a minimal example. You can continue breaking down the statement where it fails. First evaluate `X-xs`, then `(X-xs)**2`, and so on. at any point, the actual shape is not the expected. I hope you can boil it down to one operator behaving strangely.  Also: which version of [tag:numpy] do you use?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have numpy 1.9.2-8 @Dr.V

Comment: I found the problem it messes up when puting X or Y in it. This is what i had before: `N = 51 x_start, x_end = -1, 2 # x-direction boundaries` `y_start, y_end = -0.5, 0.5 # y-direction boundaries` `x = np.linspace(x_start, x_end, N) # creates a 1D-array for x` `y = np.linspace(y_start, y_end, N) # creates a 1D-array for y` `X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y) # generates a mesh grid` @Dr.V